# Inconsistency with selenium driver.find_element

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to input a password into a box using Python. This is the HTML part of the webpage that includes the box to type in.

```
<input type="password" placeholder="" name="password" id="input6" value="" aria-label="" autocomplete="off" class="password-with-toggle">
```

My code is this:

```
pass_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'input6')
pass_box.send_keys(password)
```

It works every once in a while but is not consistent at all. The HTML does not change. Putting in the username and clicking the next button works, but will throw an error every now and then when it comes to the password box. The error says unable to locate element.

Follow up question:
One of the html items does not have a name  or an id. This is the html part of the code:

input class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Verify" data-type="save

I have tried find_element_by_css_selector and find_element_by_xpath using class and value. Neither work and I'm not sure what to try next. I'm trying to just click the verify button to verify credentials.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be the element was not available at that time. you can use the Webdriver `wait` in that case.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)

pass_box = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'input6')))
action.move_to_element(pass_box).click().perform()
```

Or you can also use -

```
pass_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'input6')))
action.move_to_element(pass_box).click().perform()
```

Try the above codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
        
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'input6')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
```

After this you can also do `time.sleep(2)` to make it wait extra but that is a little expensive